# Filter a multidimensional array by another array in javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, filter

I'm trying to filter an array, from another array :

I have the first array :

```
var json = [["ID1", "Person1", "10"], ["ID2", "Person2", "20.0"], ["ID3", "Person3", "50.0"], ["ID4", "Person4", "40.0"]];
```

My filter array : (which is not ordered);

```
var filter = ["ID4", "ID1"];
```

And the result I would like to have :

```
var json = [["ID1", "Person1", "10"], ["ID4", "Person4", "40.0"]];
```

or

```
var json = [["ID4", "Person4", "40"], ["ID1", "Person1", "10.0"]];
```

Comment: Or just plain old iteration -> http://jsfiddle.net/NWQJV/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
json = json.filter(function(v) { return filter.indexOf(v[0])!==-1 })
```

But I'd recommend you to avoid naming `json` a variable not holding some JSON.

If you want to be compatible with IE8, I'd recommend to [use a shim for filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) or simply to iterate using 2 `for` loops.

Comment: That's the best solution for newer browsers, but not supported in IE8 or below. +1, but it looks strange with variable names like `json` and `filter` !

Comment: It works great thanks!
I'll check the alternative for IE8, since I'll need it.
Thanks!